# Не могу поймать логи в python

Tags: python, c, логирование

Пытаюсь компилировать файлы С через `os.system`, а потом ловить логи с ошибками. Пробовал такое решение:

```
import os
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename="logfile.log"):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "a")

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.terminal, attr)

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

    def flush(self):
        pass

def compile_c(file_name: str):
    """
    Compile C file
    """
    os.system(f"gcc {file_name}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.stdout = Logger()
    compile_c("a.c")
    # print("Hello world")
```

Ошибки, которые появлялись в результате компиляции a.c не ловились и не записывались в файл. Пробовал везде менять `stdout` на `stderr`, но результата такая замена не дала.

Еще интересно узнать, куда оправляются логи при правильной работе программы (допустим, когда происходит сборка проекта с помощью `make`), и как определить, какие логи содержать информацию об ошибке (следовательно компиляция не удалась).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов системной команды через `os.system` выполняется в `shell` - подпроцессе и не дает возможности получить код возврата и содержимое потоков вывода. Для таких задач необходимо использовать функционал модуля [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

В самом простом случае скрипт, вызывающий компилятор, выглядит так:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['gcc', 'test.c']).check_returncode()
```

Поток вывода компилятора будет направлен в терминал, из которого вызван скрипт (общий вывод для вызываемой команды и интерпретатора).

Вызов `subprocess.run` возвращает объект типа `CompletedProcess`, метод `check_returncode` которого бросает исключение в том случае, если код возврата выполняемой команды отличен от 0. Можно добавить обработчик исключения для совершения дополнительных действий.

У самой функции [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) есть параметры для более гибкого управления потоками `I/O`.

Еще более расширенным функционалом обладает менее высокоуровневый класс [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

---

**P.S.** Если реальная задача - это не освоение принципов и способов совершения вызовов системных функций из питона, а именно сборка проектов на `C/C++`, то полезно будет обратить внимание на готовые системы сборки.

1. [Waf](https://gitlab.com/ita1024/waf/tree/master)
2. [SCons](https://github.com/SCons/scons)
3. [Обзор систем сборки SCons и Waf](https://habr.com/ru/post/95693/)